# Why did A.M.A.Z.O. transport Oa into another dimension?

Tags: dc, tv, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

Professor Ivo's nanotechnology based Android A.M.A.Z.O. was intellectual who used to do anything due to a reason. He wasn't the one who could screw someone just under the lust of power.

Why did he transport Oa into another dimension?

Answer (score 6):

To prevent the Oans from being able to interfere with his plans. While no single Green Lantern could be a real threat to Amazo, a collection of them backed by the powers of one of the oldest and most powerful species in the Universe, might give him pause. By transferring Oa to another dimension, it would ensure they would be unable to stop him before he managed to get his revenge on particular members of the human race, i.e. Lex Luthor.

As Luthor surmised what the android sought was a purpose for all of his considerable ability. He had great power but limited imagination. Fortunately, Dr. Fate intervened and took the android away to discover what true potential could be achieved by Amazo if guided by a gentle and concerned hand.

Comment: Why would Oa show interest against his plan?

Comment: Because that is what the Oans created the Green Lantern Corps specifically to do. To protect young species from more advanced technologies or individuals with the ability to disrupt the natural order of the Universe's development (such as the Oan's saw fit). The Oans would intervene only if the threat were such that the Green Lanterns could not effectively stop it. Amazo's powers had grown so much he could even be a threat to the Guardians...

Answer (score 5):

AMAZO actually answers this in the episode, because it was in his way.

Here's a Youtube video with the quote: (Quote starts at 1:25)

Amazo: I did not destroy Oa - I simply moved it to another dimension. (everyone stares) It was in my way.

John Stewart: Then could you move it back?

(Amazo's eyes glow briefly)

Amazo: Done.